# co_e_server_exec_failure when instantiating com server via windows service

Tags: com

When instantiating a com server object via windows service and using a service account defined on the domain for that I get hresult 0x80080005 server execution failed. According to stack trace the CreateInstance fails.

Running the process by dbl click as the logged in user, problem not happening and instance created.
Also when running the process from a scheduled task with this domain user it hits same failure. Using a local administrator user from scheduled task will not fail.

I tried adding permissions to this administrator group domain user in various places including on the exe itself, the containing folder, the clsid node in the registry.
In the dcom config, the component doesn’t appear even though I did /regserver and the registry seems to be correct when I look at it.

This problem occurs on a newly installed machine (windows 2016) but not on the old ones (windows 2008, windows 7).

The com component is MapForce.exe and I instantiate it via c# ‘new MapForceLib.Application()’ which as mentioned does work on other machines.

Any ideas to further debug?

Comment: CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE is a pretty generic error code that means the COM server failed to answer badly (crash, invalid pointer dereference, segmentation fault, etc.). The root cause is a bug in the COM server code (from what you say it may be due to an environmental change like new OS versions, etc.). You should debug it or contact the vendor if you don't own it.